# Create method that is not called in the browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a method in a controller that I **don't** want the user to call it from the browser. This method is called by other methods in the controller which do return a view. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set this method as private and not public.